# Combine entries in an array then merge the data? (JSON + JS) (Example provided)

Tags: node.js, arrays

I am working with Node.js, and I am trying to overlay entries from my data.json file to output them in a new output.json file. The intent here is that the entries in the data.json are overlayed, with matching item names taking their values from the higher structures in the 'stack'.

e.g.

```
{
  fred: {
    john: 'batman',
    james: 'hero'
  }
}
```

overlayed with

```
{
  john: 'tailor',
  fred: {
    james: 'robin'
  }
}
```

results in

```
{
  john: 'tailor',
  fred: {
    john: 'batman',
    james: 'robin'
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code, that you tried to solve this problem...